# Angular Factory Manipulating Data (CRUD) with function in the Factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple Angular App that uses a factory to pull a list of items from a "JSON" file.  Eventually this will be connected to a database but for now I'm starting with just pulling from a static file.  The JSON file contains an array of items. I'm really trying to understand how do I get a reference to my data in the factory after the promise has been returned to the controller.

My Factory is setup as follows:

angular.module("myApp").factory("ServiceTypeFactory", ['$http',  function ($http ) {

```
return {
    ServiceTypes: function () {
        return $http.get('json/servicetypes.json').success
        (
            function (data) {
               return data;
            });
    },



    find: function (id) {
      return  _.findWhere(data, {ID:id}); // Not sure how to get access to the data
    }
}
```

}]);

This works great I can share the Factory across multiple controllers.  The part I'm missing is how do I reference a specific array item from my json file and update it in my controller.  I'm not following how to get a reference to the actual data so when I modify the item in one controller it the change would be reflected in another controller.

In both of my controllers I have the following code to get a reference to the data initially.

```
var popService = function (data) {
        $scope.ServiceTypes = data;
    }

    // IF at ANY time the Service Types have not been loaded we will populate them.

    if (typeof $scope.ServiceTypes === "undefined") {
        ServiceTypeFactory.ServiceTypes().success(popService); 
    }
```

My understanding is my  $scope.ServiceTypes has really a reference to the data.  How do I back in my factory in a function get access to the actual single source of my data.  I get that the factory returns the data with functions an object but I'm missing how to reference this data back in my factory to manipulate it. In the future I want to perform CRUD operations on it for the time being I'm just trying to work out the mechanics.

What my JSON file looks like:

```
 {
    "serviceTypes": [
        {
            "ID": "1001",
            "ServiceTypeName": "111111",
            "Description": "aaaaaaa"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1002",
            "ServiceTypeName": "222222",
            "Description": "bbbbbbb"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1003",
            "ServiceTypeName": "3333333",
            "Description": "ccccccc"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1004",
            "ServiceTypeName": "444444",
            "Description": "dddddddd"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1005",
            "ServiceTypeName": "5555555",
            "Description": "eeeeeee"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know if your way is the best way to test CRUD. 

You could use an array like $scope.users: http://jsfiddle.net/charms/eP7T8/

    $scope.users = [{id:"31546310-8a09-4887-9bca-7a719af0620e", firstName:"John", lastName:"Smith", email:"john@john.com", password:"bla"}, {id:"62637e0b-c7e6-44c7-bd1e-8f6130eb648f", firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Adams", email:"jane@jane.com", password:"bla"}];

Or you could use $httpBackend with $resource if you want to test CRUD with REST: 

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend

I don't know if this is useful for you but I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is I can update this data in two different controllers and I want the data to be bound to both controllers.  It is like I want the data to truly be stored in the factory.  So no matter what controller updates it the Data will be then digested to the other controllers. My issue is not knowing how to reference the true source of the data.  I don't want to access it in the scope.  I want it stored in one spot.

Comment: Try http://egghead.io sharing data between controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to clean the code up a little.  Watching a couple of quick example on [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) made it clear.